# CommonAPI Dbus Performance

Tags: ipc, dbus

1. Does Genivi's CommonAPI-Dbus can be used for frequent data transfer across process (around 15-20ms frequency). The data transfer size would be approximately 250 bytes for a single transfer.
2. If performance issue persists for DBus, how can we extend CommonAPI binding to use other IPC such as Posix MQueue instead of Dbus

Comment: Standard D-Bus can be used for that, yes. I don’t know what Genivi do to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. From my (professional) experience, yes. Performance-wise, it should be very similar to standard D-Bus. Measure it if you have some doubts. You need to think whether other applications are heavily using d-bus, whether your SoC is performant, whether low latency is very important or it can be delayed a bit.
2. You will need to create your own binding tools (code generator) and binding runtime. I think it is not trivial and I don't have experience in writing custom binding tools and its runtime library.
   Perhaps, you can start looking at the design concept of CommonAPI:
   https://genivi.github.io/capicxx-core-tools/ .
   GENIVI also has another binding called SomeIP which can be a reference to write your own binding.

- https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-someip-tools
- https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-someip-runtime